# jQuery select change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire an alert depending on which value is selected from a `<select>` element using jQuery:

```
$("#optiontype").change( function () {
        var option = $("#optiontype").val();
        if(option.Contains("Forward")){
            alert("forward selected");
        }
    });
```

The alert never fires whenever I choose 'forward' from the `<select>` element.

Comment: Do you have a `.Contains` function? It's not available by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change is the right event. The problem is that contains is not right in this case. Contains is for DOM traversal. What you need to use here is just a normal comparison like so:

```
$("#optiontype").change( function () {
    var option = $("#optiontype").val();
    if(option.toLowerCase() == "forward"){
        alert("forward");
    }
});
```

Or if the string can contain more than just "forward", check out indexOf: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 2):

You should use `option.indexOf("forward") != -1`

Comment: This works...however, the option for selection is actually 'Forward'...why does 'forward' work? Surely "wHaTEvEr iS In HeRe iS CaSe sEnSiSiTiVe?"

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#optiontype").change( function () {
        var option = $("#optiontype").val();
        if(option.toLowerCase()=="forward"){
            alert("forward selected");
        }
    });
```

That is if you are getting the actual value of a select element, not the text. See the difference:

```
<select id="optiontype" type="multiple">
 <option value="forward">forwardtext</option>
</select>
```

If you are looking for the text then use:

```
$("#optiontype").change( function () {
        var option = $("#optiontype option:selected").text();
        if(option.toLowerCase()=="forwardtext"){
            alert("forward selected");
        }
    });
```